# Rotating new coordinates by the same rotation

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations, python

I am starting with a matrix $A$ and making a complicated rotation in n dimensions, resulting in the matrix $B$. I am making the rotation and move back again to the original matrix $A$ using an $n*n$ matrix with a determinant of 1.

Suppose now that I have new coordinate points related to B, and I want to apply exactly the same inverse rotation to find their predicted coordinates in A. How would I do this? My rotation matrix is the wrong size.

I am not a mathematician - I'm trying to program this in python. So please go easy on me!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you provided an example and better defined your terms.  I surmise you have $B=RA$.  Is $R$ known?  Is $A$ known?  New coordinate points related to $B$.  Not sure what this means.  Generally to get from $B$ back to $A$ you would invert your rotation matrix.  If it is a proper rotation matrix $R^{-1} = R^T$.  Not sure what you mean by the rotation matrix is the wrong size.

Comment: Yes B = RA and R and A are known for the original matrix. Let's say my A matrix is 5x5, which contains data relating to a time series. I rotate this matrix with a 5x5 unitary matrix R. My resulting B matrix also has a different representation of this time series. This different representation allows me to predict the next points in the series. So now I have a 8x5 time series. What I want to do is now inverse the rotation R for all of this data. However, because my rotation matrix is 5x5 it is not big enough to rotate the new 8x5 B matrix. I'm wondering how to find the points in

Comment: A corresponding to the remaining 3 rows of B

Comment: OK.  So in your example, the dimension 5 represents a vector which is transformed and 8 represents samplings of that vector at different points in time?  In your example R can operate on a matrix M which is 5xN where N can be any value.  I think this is what you are getting at, but you are combining two concepts, time series modeling and rotations.  It seems that what you are looking for is $R^TB^T$, but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks, it works! It was B@R.T. If you want to write it up i'll mark it as the solution